# Whenever I'm going to login or register with strapi 405(method not allowed) message come up

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postman, strapi, insomnia

Whenever i'm sending request to strapi for login and register I'm getting error like 405

[image: Image displaying the error in Insomnia]

Comment: This is an application level issue in your server, check your server logs for the process that is running on your port.

Comment: The api should be `http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local/register` notice that you are missing `api/` part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is because your API route might be wrong.
In my case, it's working fine with **http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local**

Also, you can check that API route with the below path in your **strapi administration panel**

Setting -> USERS & PERMISSIONS PLUGIN -> Roles -> Select Authenticated or Public -> Permissions

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: how did you know its http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local? I only know dashboard URL: http://localhost:1337/admin/.

Comment: @bandungeuy it will appear in Setting -> USERS & PERMISSIONS PLUGIN -> Roles -> Select Authenticated or Public -> Permissions

Comment: And where is exactly I can find the url? Already in Permissions sub-menu. I just found: Content-type-builder, email, i18n, Upload, and Users Permission.